# How can i only keep number alphabetical letter in my String

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to remove all the strange symbol out of my string.
only keep some [A-Z][a-z][0-9][" ' : ; / ? . , < > ` ~ ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) ]
in my string.
Example

```
String a="abc:d(E) ƒ†â¥‡";
```

Result will be:

```
a="abc:d(E)";
```

I only just study about java regex a little. 
Would you help me with this.

My code until now

```
a=a.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+, "")
```

don't know to add the [* & ^ ..] part

Comment: We don't write code for you. Provide us a code example what you have tried and maybe we can give you some remarks on how to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `replaceAll`, like this:

```
a = a.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9\"'<and so on>]", "");
```

Note the `^` at the beginning of the character range: it means "all characters *not* covered by the rest of the list in square brackets".

Since the replacement is an empty string, the characters matching the regex would be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a string with all of the bad chars, and simply check every string you have to with the bad character string. If you find a bad character, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

[Throughout the documentation of this class, the phrase "matching character" is used to mean "any character c for which this.matches(c) returns true".](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html)